# JQuery Sortable Drag and Drop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I've implemented the JQuery drag and drop functionality recently and i've found a slight bug. I can drag my element the smallest amount and it'll still be assigned when I decide to drop it because I don't want to drag that element anymore.

How do I check that element is above the table which I want to drop my selected element into?

**How drag and drop works at moment (Only have to drag slightly)**

[image]

**How it should work (Don't want it to be able to slightly drag)**

[image]

**Sortable code:**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{

$("#Assign tbody").sortable(
{
    connectWith: "#Assign tbody",
    scroll: false,
    cursor: 'move',
    stop: function (event, info)
    {
        alert("Done Assign");
    }
}).disableSelection();

$("#Remove tbody").sortable(
{
    connectWith: "#Remove tbody",
    scroll: false,
    cursor: 'move',
    stop: function (event, info)
    {
        alert("Done Remove");
    }
}).disableSelection();
});
```

**JS Fiddle Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lhk941tc/

Comment: Please include your current code. We can't help without seeing the code.

Comment: @Mooseman updated my answer with little example